# Append div to element and set equal height and width

Tags: jquery, append

I would like to append a div to some(any) element in my document. The div should have the same height and width as the element its being appended to. I put up an example on [JsFiddle(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/cu2gD/5/):

```
$('body *').each(function() {
    var t = $(this), 
        w = t.width().toFixed(), 
        h = t.height().toFixed();
    t.prepend('<div class="over" style="height:'+h+'px;width:'+w+'px;">'+w+' + '+h+'</div>');
});
```

In the example Im using `H2`. The problem is that if I look at the H2 in my chrome console it has these `dimensions:420px + 40px`. But my appended div is giving me **`419px + 23px`**.

I can solve it by removing the css from the H2 but I really would like to keep that. So how do I set the proper dimensions for the appended div like I see it in my console? (I tried events `prepend`, `append`, `appendTo`, `before`, `insertBefore`, `after` etc. with no luck)

Comment: try to reset your h2 by adding it in the css with body : body, h2 {margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: so the problem in height only?

Comment: @ebram tharwat No its also the width (the code is just an example)

Comment: @Mohamed Ali That doesn't seem to do it

Comment: Maybe I should use `attr('style')` from the `H2` and apply it on the new div, the problem hoewever would be the padding of internal text,pics etc...